# How to produce overlapping QQ plots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I would like to make an overlapping QQ-plot from the GWAS results similar to the attached figure. I have run two GWAS analyses and want to generate a figure where the QQ-plot from both GWAS are overlaid on one another. I am using the R-package "qqman" for that.

Can someone please tell me how to do that in R?

Thank you.

Sample figure
[image: Sample figure]

Comment: Hello! Please show us what you've have done so far.

Comment: So, I have two GWAS results files. I have used the following codes to produce separate QQ-plots.

## Dataset 1
`library(qqman)`
`library(ggplot2)`
`a <- read.table ("gemma_GWAS_1.assoc.txt", header=T)`

`dat_df <- data.frame(a$chr, a$rs, a$ps, a$p_lrt)`

`colnames(dat_df) <-c('CHR','SNP','BP', 'P')`

`pdf("GWAS_1.pdf", height=6, width=8, useDingbats=F)`

`qq(dat_df$P)`

`dev.off()`

This produces one QQ-plot. The same code is used to produce the second plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the R package `CMplot` for producing overlapping QQ plots in R.

```
library(CMplot)

data(pig60K) 
pig60K$trait1[sample(1:nrow(pig60K), round(nrow(pig60K)*0.80))] <- NA
pig60K$trait2[sample(1:nrow(pig60K), round(nrow(pig60K)*0.25))] <- NA
CMplot(pig60K,plot.type="q",col=c("dodgerblue1", "olivedrab3", "darkgoldenrod1"),threshold=1e-6,
        ylab.pos=2,signal.pch=c(19,6,4),signal.cex=1.2,signal.col="red",conf.int=TRUE,box=FALSE,multracks=
        TRUE,cex.axis=2,file="jpg",memo="",dpi=300,file.output=TRUE,verbose=TRUE,ylim=c(0,8),width=5,height=5)
```

[image: Multi_tracks Q-Q plot]

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
(abd = data.frame(a = runif(100, 0, 3),
                  b = runif(100, 346, 455),
                  d = runif(100, 3952, 4903)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_qq(aes(sample = a, color = "a")) +
  geom_qq(aes(sample = b, color = "b")) + 
  geom_qq(aes(sample = d, color = "d")) +
  theme_minimal())
```

I'm not sure what your objective is exactly, but more than likely the data will overlap and hide important information. Perhaps what you really need is a bi-variate or multi-variate version of a qq plot? A chi-square qq plot using the Mahalanobis distance might be a better bet, if that's the case.

This plot will show with the arguments set for it with `MVN::mvn()`

```
abd = data.frame(a = runif(100, 0, 3),
                 b = runif(100, 346, 455),
                 d = runif(100, 3952, 4903))

MVN::mvn(abd, multivariatePlot = "qq", multivariateOutlierMethod = "quan")
```

You can manually create the chi-square qq plot this way:

```
(cvAbd = cov(and))            # covariance matrix

(dif = scale(abd, scale = F)) # scaling 

# solve() used in next call calculates the inverse matrix 
(d = diag(dif %*% 
   solve(cvAbd) %*%           # matrix multiplication
   t(dif)))   

(r = rank(d))                 # ranking 

n = dim(abd)[1]  # number of observations
p = dim(abd)[2]  # number of variables

(ch <- qchisq((r - 0.5)/n, p))    # determine chi-square quantiles

ggplot(data = data.frame(d = d, ch = ch), 
       aes(d, ch)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("Chi-Square Q-Q Plot") + 
  xlab("Squared Mahalanobis Distance") +
  ylab("Chi-Square Quantile") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

You were looking for something different -- try this
you can replace `runif(10000,.5,1)` with your data,

-`o` and `e` for the same vector (same data in both)

-`o2` and `e2` is a second vector or second model (same data in both)
This uses plotly...

```
# first model
o = -log10(sort(runif(10000,.5,1), decreasing = FALSE))
e = -log10(ppoints(length(runif(10000,.5,1))))

# second model
o2 = -log10(sort(runif(10000,0,1), decreasing = FALSE))
e2 = -log10(ppoints(length(runif(10000,0,1))))

plotly::plot_ly(x = ~e, y = ~o, name = "p1", 
                type = "scatter", mode = "markers")  %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~e2, y = ~o2, name = "p2") %>% 
  add_trace(x = c(0, max(e,e2)), y = c(0, max(e,e2)), 
            mode="lines", name = "Log normal") %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Expected -log[10](<i>p</i>)'),
         yaxis = list(title = 'Observed -log[10](<i>p</i>)'))
```

You requested a `ggplot2` version -

```
ggplot(data.frame(o = o, e = e, o2 = o2, e2 = e2), 
       aes(e, o, color = "First Model")) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(o2, e2, color = "Second Model")) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color = "darkred") +
  scale_color_discrete("") +
  xlab(expression(paste('Expected -log[10](', italic('p'),')'))) +
  ylab(expression(paste('Observed -log[10](', italic('p'),')'))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. As I am doing GWAS with two different models, I found out one performs better than the other. So, I want to overlay both and show the differences in the deviation rather than putting two QQ plots side by side. As these are GWAS data, the R-package QQman adjusts the x-axis and y-axis as shown in the figure attached. Does your code do a similar thing here in terms of scaling the axis on a negative log10 scale?

Comment: I edited the answer with something that works for you, I think!

Comment: Hi @Kat, is there any way to use the above `plot_ly` code in the `ggplot2`. That will make life easier to save the resulting image.

Comment: Saving a `ggplot` to a variable, `gg <- ggplot(...)`,  and then calling `ggplotly(gg)`, will produce a plotly version of a specified ggplot